# SPF records for a company with traveling (or remote) employees

Tags: smtp, spf

I'm trying to set up a SPF record for the domain of a company whose employees use all sorts of SMTP servers..

But I think that line already contradicts itself ? Is this a problem ?

They use several SMTP servers, partly because they are travelling, partly because they work at home, partly because they don't know what it means anyway. Is there a way to solve that ?

Comment: How are they using "all sorts of" SMTP servers? Don't they use a company-mail-account which is using the company mailservers and DNS records under the company's control?

Comment: If they don't use a central company SMTP server, make sure they do - you can not expect reliable mail service otherwise.

Comment: Why do they use all sorts of SMTP servers?

Comment: Setting up the SPF policy with `-all` should stop it, though. Problem: solved.

Comment: @Lenniey no they don't. They use their providers SMTP. I get the impression y'all want me to open up an smtp server for the world, which  ... is an option. Is that necessary ?

Comment: @EsaJokinen what problem did you just solve ? :-)

Comment: The problem of using all sort of SMTP servers. But I finally had time to write an actual answer.

Comment: `I'm trying to set up a SPF record for the domain of a company whose employees use all sorts of SMTP servers` - This implies that they all have company related email addresses. We then naturally inferred that there is a mail server that handles incoming email for the company domain name and we are wondering why they aren't using this server to send outbound email.

Comment: @joeqwerty That is why I wrote *because* ... in the question. If that reasoning is wrong, you can address that in an answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> They use several SMTP servers, partly because they are travelling, partly because they work at home

This was very common back in the 1990s, when the same SMTP configuration was used for both delivering mail between *message transfer agents* (MTA) and initial submission from the *mail user agent* (MUA). Also, in order to fight spam from compromised computers, ISPs started to block traffic to SMTP port `TCP/25` for other destinations than their own outbound SMTP server. This led to the described situation, where employees used to change the SMTP server every time they switched location, but this day and age **this all should be history**.

Separating message submission from the SMTP between MTAs & optionally requiring authentication was first introduced in [RFC 2476](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2476) (Dec 1998), while the current updated standard is in [RFC 6409](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6409). In short this means that your SMTP listens on port `587` with different settings for MUAs. These connections are usually authenticated, encrypted and not blocked by the ISPs, making it unnecessary to switch SMTP servers anymore.

Using separated message submission for all outbound mail is the first step towards stopping email forgery; SPF, DKIM and DMARC are tools you can only use once you have suspended practices that make it impossible to distinguish forged mail from genuine.

> partly because they don't know what it means anyway. Is there a way to solve that?

This is a job for the ICT department! The employees don't need to know why they must use certain settings for their email. **The ICT department should provide the correct email settings** and guidance for using them, and declare these are the only correct settings for sending email. Then, this can be enforced using SPF, DKIM and DMARC; setting up the strict policies will stop all other mail from the domain, as it technically becomes forged.

Comment: this history lesson explains a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  Does your remote employees make use of your VPN server or not?

If you have a VPN server then the SPF setting is normal for a regular SMTP/MX mail server:

```
v=spf1 *.example.com -all
```

If not VPN, then it is by SMTP MSA (mail submission agent) via Internet-facing TCP port 576, configured for mail relay, frequently requiring some form of anti-spam support (i.e.,spamassassin), all which requires a lengthy list of authorized remote IP addresses:

```
v=spf1 ipv4:myserverip ?include:_spf.example.com -all
```

or a wildcard SPF (neither are ideal):

```
v=spf1 * -all
```

Ideally, VPN is the better and secured solution for remote workers.

Comment: An SPF policy that allows everything would be rather pointless...

Comment: Also, VPN is broader solution. This problem is usually solved with SMTP *submission*.

Comment: @EsaJokinen so, tell us more about SMTP *submission*

Comment: Not even a single of these examples have a valid syntax.